# Accessing Relationship Objects (CoreData)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

In my core data model I have two entities, let's call them A and B, A holds multiple B objects (`A<-->>B`). `allBObjects` is the To-Many Relationship that holds the B objects.

As this code

```
[[AObject valueForKey:@"allBObjects"] count];
```

works, I thought that this should work too:

```
[[AObject valueForKey:@"allBObjects"] objectAtIndex:index];
```

However it doesn't, as the relationship objects do not seem to be stored as arrays. Does anybody know how to access objects in `allBObjects` of `AObject`?

I would appreciate some help, Fabian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [Cocoa Dev Central: Core Data Class Overview](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000086.php#8):

> Managed Objects have no actual order
>   in the Context or in Relationships. In
>   fact, the "native" collection class
>   for Core Data is NSSet. You can order
>   the results of Fetch Request using
>   NSSortDescriptors, but the sorting is
>   not saved to the data store.

Try

```
 [[[[AObject valueForKey:@"allBObjects"] objectAtIndex:index] allObjects] objectAtIndex:index];
```